# VBA code for running through pivot tables and changing filters/labels

Tags: vba, excel

Effectively I am trying to create some VBA code that will loop through a bunch of sheets with pivot tables, apply certain conditions to the pivot tables (i.e. change the fields depending on a variable/change the filter depending on a cell value, as I have tried to demonstrate in the code below). This doesn't even come close to running (I am a complete beginner trying to update legacy code), so I am looking for pointers as to how to use the variables defined for the results I want.

My current issue is that I can't seem to call the PivotTable to start changing fields etc.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim MyPivot As PivotTable
Dim NewCat As String

Sub RefreshPivots()

 For Each MySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each MyPivot In MySheet.PivotTables
        NewCat = Worksheets("WorkingSheet").Range("B44").Value
        MyPivot.RefreshTable

        With ActiveSheet
         .MyPivot.AddDataField
         .MyPivot.PivotFields ("GuidelinePercent"), "Count of GuidelinePercent", xlCount
        End With

    Next MyPivot
 Next MySheet
```

(A lot more will go in the loop, this is just the first issue I have encountered).

I am getting: `Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method` on line

`With ActiveSheet.MyPivot.AddDataField`

Any help would be great!

EDIT;

When trying

```
With ActiveSheet
.PivotTables(MyPivot).AddDataField
.PivotTables(MyPivot).PivotFields ("GuidelinePercent"), "Count of GuidelinePercent", xlCount
End With
```

I get `Run-time error'1004': Unable to get the Pivot Tables property of the Worksheet class` on the line `.MyPivot.AddDataField`.

Comment: Your code didn't specify the `pivotfield` to be added.

Comment: I think I am getting an error before that is even an issue... I will add a line of me (attempting to) adding a field.

Comment: For the EDIT, include quotation marks: `.PivotTables("MyPivot")`

Comment: @Egalth No, `MyPivot` is not the name of the pivot.

Comment: I tried this but it made no difference to the error. MyPivot is already = "PivotTable2" (depending on which sheet I am on), so would this matter?

Comment: Ok. @kulapo, of course, I was too quick.

Comment: @alex1stef2 read my answer and code below, see if it works as you intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a loop of `For Each MySheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, so when you are using later `With ActiveSheet` it is not the same sheet as `MySheet`, infact you don't need to use `ActiveSheet`, you can use directly the `PivotTable` object you name `MyPivot`.

Try the code below:

```
 With MyPivot
     .AddDataField .PivotFields("GuidelinePercent"), "Count of GuidelinePercent", xlCount
 End With
```

**Edit 1**:

```
 Dim PvtFld As PivotField

 With MyPivot
     On Error Resume Next
     Set PvtFld = .PivotFields("GuidelinePercent")
     On Error GoTo 0
     If PvtFld Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "Error in setting the PivotField"
     Else
         .AddDataField PvtFld, "Count of " & PvtFld.Name, xlCount
     End If
 End With
```

Comment: I have been trying things very similar to this and this version is clearly the most concise but I still get a runtime error of: `Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable class`.

Comment: Kulapo just deleted his answer but when hovering over MyPivot just before the error it is equal to "PivotTable2" and if I manually go to this pivot table and click on it, the PivotTable Field List definitely lists GuidelinePercent as an option.

Comment: @alex1stef2 let me add a debug option to my code, try the code under **Edit 1**

Comment: Okay it looks like this has worked, no need at all for the error message! I am unsure as to why, it could just be that your first suggestion was fine and I didn't redefine a pivot field at the top! Thank you so much, I will try to use this format going forward to get everything to work well! - will you be willing to return here and answer any questions if I have more problems?

Comment: @alex1stef2 sure, but you should open a new post if it is related to another issue (so future users won't be confused) , ok ?

Comment: ok! though quickly, how do I completely clear all filters and axes at the start of the loop so that I can rerun my code without any issues?

Comment: @alex1stef2 you mean of all PivotTables ? use `MyPivot.ClearAllFilters`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153775/discussion-between-alex1stef2-and-shai-rado).